# IOS Crash Report unable to analyze stack trace

Tags: ios, swift, crash

Would really appreciate if someone could point me in right direction. My app was rejected by apple app review board stating that the application crashed at launch. Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce the crash. The relevant sections of the symbolicated crash log are listed below. Would really appreciate some guidance on resolving this

```
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Havana [11291]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7168627A-AC55-4E81-9FE0-05228C71B31E/Havana.app/Havana
Identifier:          au.com.nextx.havana
Version:             6 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           au.com.nextx.havana [3636]

Date/Time:           2018-09-10 18:04:16.6495 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-09-10 18:04:15.6077 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)
Baseband Version:    6.80.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000101310d3c
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000101310d3c 0x101160000 + 1772860
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000101310d3c 0x101160000 + 1772860
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001011a8094 0x101160000 + 295060
3   Havana                          0x0000000100dea374 @objc AppDelegate.applicationWillResignActive(_:) + 172916 (AppDelegate.swift:0)
4   UIKit                           0x000000018f06ddbc -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 408
5   UIKit                           0x000000018f06d1c4 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3484
6   UIKit                           0x000000018f03a5e0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1680
7   UIKit                           0x000000018f66ab1c __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 784
8   UIKit                           0x000000018f039dd0 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
9   UIKit                           0x000000018f039c6c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 240
10  UIKit                           0x000000018f038afc -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 724
11  UIKit                           0x000000018fcce84c __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 296
12  UIKit                           0x000000018f0381ec -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 432
13  UIKit                           0x000000018fab3ac8 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
14  UIKit                           0x000000018fc01bf8 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
15  UIKit                           0x000000018f037c0c -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 248
16  UIKit                           0x000000018f0375a8 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 368
17  UIKit                           0x000000018f0345e0 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
18  UIKit                           0x000000018f034330 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364
19  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000187c60470 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364
20  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000187c68d6c __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184d50a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184d58170 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
23  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000187c94878 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
24  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000187c9451c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
25  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000187c94ab8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
26  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185407404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
27  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185406c2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
28  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018540479c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185324da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
30  GraphicsServices                0x000000018730a020 GSEventRunModal + 100
31  UIKit                           0x000000018f344758 UIApplicationMain + 236
32  Havana                          0x0000000100dc7e88 main + 32392 (ThresholdPanGesture.swift:13)
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000184db5fc0 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184ee5d78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185083eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185083b08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185083b04 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185083b04 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184ec3de8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184ec3c60 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185406e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185404908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185324da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5   Foundation                      0x0000000185d99674 -[NSRunLoop+ 34420 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x0000000185d994dc -[NSRunLoop+ 34012 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 84
7   UIKit                           0x000000018f029768 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x0000000185ea9efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185085220 _pthread_body + 272
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185085110 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185083b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185083b04 start_wqthread + 0
```

Comment: Are you calling any facebook sdk api in class `ThresholdPanGesture.swift` ?

Comment: Something wrong in your `applicationWillResignActive` method.

Comment: @ Rahul: No Facebook API

Comment: @Harsh: I commented every line of code before re-submitting it to AppStore and it still crashed

Comment: @sumeetlakhwani: Why would you comment the code before submitting to app store review? Try to run the app using your testflight credentials and see if it is working correctly.